# React Native Actively Changing a StackNavigator Header Color

Tags: react-native, styles, dynamic-programming, background-color, stack-navigator

**UPDATE:**

I'm not making progress with the previous question, so I'm changing it hoping I could find another answer

I'm making an application in React Native, and I'm trying to implement a feature that will change the color of the header and then immediately see the change.

I have a global style sheet that I import and use everywhere in my app

```
var globalStyles = Stylesheet.create({
    menuHex: {
        backgroundColor: '#6ed168'
    }
    ...other styles...
})
```

The menu uses the following code. The Variable 'DrawerStack' on line 2 has all my screens on it, but that's not important. On line 6 I use the variable 'globalStyles.menuHex' that comes from the style sheet in my last code snippet

```
const DrawerNavigation = StackNavigator({
    DrawerStack: {screen: DrawerStack },
}, {
    headerMode:'float',
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
        headerStyle: globalStyles.menuHex,
        title: 'Application',
        headerTintColor: 'black',
        headerLeft: <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle')
                    }}>
                       <Image source = {menuIcon}/>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
})
```

})

I then have this function to change the hex value of the 'menuHex variable'

```
changetheme(itemValue){
    this.setState({theme: itemValue})
    if(itemValue === 'spring'){
      globalStyles.menuHex = {backgroundColor: '#6ed168'}        
    }
    else if(itemValue === 'summer'){
      globalStyles.menuHex = {backgroundColor: '#ffff00'}
    }
    else if(itemValue === 'autumn'){
      globalStyles.menuHex = {backgroundColor: '#ffa500'}
    }
    else if(itemValue === 'winter'){
      globalStyles.menuHex = {backgroundColor: '#ADD8E6'}

    } 

}
```

My problem is that when the 'menuHex' variable is changed, the change does not show until after I hit the menu toggle button or until I change pages. I want it so that the color of the header of the menu will be changed when the changetheme() function is complete. I tried running this.forceUpdate(), which did not work

Any more help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for making another question similar to this. My previous question was how to get Async Storage to block before continuing, because it wasn't before. Below was my code.

```
import globalStyles from './src/style'

setStyle = async () => {
    try{
      const itemValue =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('app_theme')
      if(itemValue == null){
        AsyncStorage.setItem('app_theme', 'spring')
        globalStyles.menuHex = {backgroundColor: '#6ed168'}
      }
      else{
        if(itemValue === 'spring'){
          globalStyles.menuHex = {backgroundColor: '#6ed168'}        }
        else if(itemValue === 'summer'){
          globalStyles.menuHex = {backgroundColor: '#ffff00'}
        }
        else if(itemValue === 'autumn'){
          globalStyles.menuHex = {backgroundColor: '#ffa500'}
        }
        else if(itemValue === 'winter'){
          globalStyles.menuHex = {backgroundColor: '#ADD8E6'}
        } 
      }
    }
    catch(error){
      console.log(error)
    }
};
```

What I ended up doing was creating a "Loading Page," which ran the function above on startup and then after it was done setting the style.menuHex variable, it changed to the Home

```
class Loading extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.setStyle(props);
  }
  async setStyle(props){
      try{
        const itemValue =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('app_theme')
        console.log(itemValue)
        if(itemValue == null){
          AsyncStorage.setItem('app_theme', 'spring')
          globalStyles.menuHex = {backgroundColor: '#6ed168'}
        }
        else{
          this.changeTheme(itemValue)
        }

      }
      catch(error){
        console.log("yup error:\n")

        console.log(error)
      }
      props.navigation.navigate('Home') //***important line. I navigate after done setting variable
  };

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
          <Text>
            Loading
          </Text>
      </View>     
    )
  }
}
```

This may not be what some people are looking for, but this method allowed me to fix my original problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined setStyle() as an async function (so it returns a Promise), you why not simply do something like this:

```
try {
  await setStyle()
  {initialize stacks}
  AppRegistry.registerComponent(...);
} catch(error) {...}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response! I cannot do that. 'await' is a reserved keyword, so I have to replace the second line with the contents of setStyle() (only what's in the try and not including the return). And even then I get a 'Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module' error. And even then that seems like poor code, to surround the main contents of the file within a try catch statement